# How to encrypt password in admincontroller fields form : prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing new module in prestashop.from this module can create new user account and there is a password field in that form.

this password field save plain text in db but i want to save that password as hash password.this is my `fields_form`

```
public function renderForm() {

$this->fields_form = [
            'tinymce' => true,
            'legend' => [
                'title' => $this->l('Edit'),
            ],
            'input' => [

                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('User name'),
                    'name' => 'username',
                    'size' => 40,
                    'lang' => false,
                    'required' => true,
                ],
[
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'label' => $this->l('Password:'),
                    'name' => 'password_hash',
                    'size' => 40,
                    'lang' => false,
                    'required' => true,
                ],
],
,
            'submit' => [
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
            ]
        ];

        if (!($obj = $this->loadObject(true)))
            return;
        return parent::renderForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the datas and encode the string inside :

```
<?php
public function postProcess()
{

    if (Tools::isSubmit('password_hash')) {
       $raw_password = Tools::getValue('password_hash');
       // Encrypt here and save
    }

}
```